# How can I sort a javascript array by three different fields?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

My Javascript array has the fields title, modifiedDate and seq

I already have this sort function:

```
            self.tests.sort(function (a, b) {
                var diff = a.title.localeCompare(b.title);
                var aDate = a.modifiedDate || "";
                var bDate = b.modifiedDate || "";
                return diff == 0 ? bDate.localeCompare(aDate) : diff;
            });
```

Now I need to extend it to sort by

1. title
2. modifiedDate
3. seq

I've only every seen a two field sort like this. How can I extend it to sort on the seq field also?

Comment: SideNote: if you don't get an acceptable answer, take a look at [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy)'s _sortBy method, or this [thenBy](https://github.com/Teun/thenBy.js) repo.

Comment: Is your array an array of objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could chain them together with logical OR `||`, because on every equal, it takes the next comparison.

Assuming, that seq is a number.

```
self.tests.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aDate = a.modifiedDate || "",
        bDate = b.modifiedDate || "";
    return a.title.localeCompare(b.title) || bDate.localeCompare(aDate) || a.seq - b.seq;
});
```